# Draggable / Expandable RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, draggable, expand

What is the newest and simplest way to do this?

All I want is the ability to drag parent items around and click them to expand to show their child items, with efficient operations if you delete or add.

Is there a library that does this and is simple to use? I tried Googling but everyone keeps saying this and that is outdated or inefficient but offer no alternatives.

Or can I just make one myself somehow? Is ItemTouchHelper what I need for expanding and moving stuff around?

Or is this built in somewhere? I'm using the support library.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time in order to find a way to implement such a list. Check out my **github** project:

https://github.com/XxGoliathusxX/LightWeightExpandableDragAndSwipeRecyclerView

If you have any questions: Just ask me ;) Hope I can safe you a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: What if you want to disable swipe to delete? Or not reorder the children, just the parents?

Comment: both possible. check out the methods in the adapter. i will take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this library](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview). It allows an expandable, draggable and swipeable `RecyclerView` with many other features.